# Java: sort a list of lists

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, point

I have a list of lists of points ie: `List<List<Point>>`.
e.g.:

```
List<Point> lp;
List<List<Point>> Llp;
Llp.add(lp);
```

`lp`would be the first line of my matrix (x=0). `Llp`is the whole matrix.

I want to get the list ascendingly sorted according to both x and y of each point. I only managed to get the internal list sorted but not the whole list. Can anyone help me please? Thank you. Here is my code to sort the internal list (ie. the first line of the matrix) according to y.

```
private void ord_horiz (List<Point> tab)
{
    boolean ordered_horiz = false;
    int size = tab.size();

    while(!ordered_horiz)
    {
        ordered_horiz = true;

        for(int i=0 ; i < size-1 ; i++)
        {
            if(tab.get(i).y > tab.get(i+1).y)
            {
                swap(tab, i, i+1);
                ordered_horiz = false;
            }
        }
        size--;
    }   
}

private void swap(List<Point> tab, int ind1, int ind2) 
{
    Point c;
    c = tab.get(ind1); 
    tab.set(ind1, tab.get(ind2));
    tab.set(ind2, c);
}
```

Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
Collections.sort(tab,new Comparator<List<Point>>(){


        @Override
        public int compare(List<Point> o1, List<Point> o2) {
            if(o1 != null && o2 !=null)
            {
                Point var1 = o1.get(0);
                            int var1_x = var1.x;
                            int var1_y = var1.y;
                Point var2 = o2.get(0);
                            int var2_x = var2.x;
                            int var2_y = var2.y;

                            Integer.compare(var1_x, var2_x);
                            Integer.compare(var1_y, var2_y);
                return /* What shall I return ? */;                 
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Here is a screenshot of my console output. I want that point to be sorted.
http://imageshack.us/scaled/large/515/38zy.png

Comment: Have you considered using [`Collections.sort(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))?

Comment: did you tried to use `Collections.sort()` ?

Comment: `Collections.sort()` only sorts one dimensional lists. I couldn't do it with my list.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more what you want to sort? How should the list of lists be sorted? For me this is not clear.

Comment: how you want to sort your external list?

Comment: you should design and think your comparator first,like you want to sort List<List<>>, what determined the seqence of the List? by the first element of the List? or other conditions?

Comment: Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080030/sorting-a-list-of-list-by-the-value-of-the-sublist

Comment: @UwePlonus I edited my question. I hope it got clearer

Comment: @Sstx I want to sort the external list according to x and y, given that x is the order of `lp` within `Llp` and y is the order of the elements of each `lp` in `Llp`.

Comment: `Collections.sort()` is the solution here; just write a custom `Comparator` and you're set.

Comment: I guess it's alright. Thank you all :)

Comment: @javacv_newbie in case you're still a little confused, I posted some example code.

Comment: @SteveP. Ah so `return list_1.size().compareTo(list_2.size());` doesn't tell that we're comparing the lists sizes? Ok I'll try it and tell you whether it worked for me or not. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @javacv_newbie You want to compare two `Point`s to sort the lists, themselves, but to sort `List<List<Point>>` you need to define a means to compare two `List<Point>`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I want to sort the external list according to x and y, given that x is
>   the order of lp within Llp and y is the order of the elements of each
>   lp in Llp."

You should use a custom comparator. As I assume each list within LLP has the same number of elements, and each list is only for a distinct X, the following should work:

### Example

```
//Create the Data

    List<List<Point>> Llp = new ArrayList<List<Point>>();

    for(int i=0; i< 50; i++)
    {
        List<Point> lp = new ArrayList<Point>();

        for(int j=0; j<50; j++)
        lp.add(new Point((int)(Math.random()*1000), i));

        Llp.add(lp);
    }



    // The comparators
    Comparator<List<Point>> comparator_rows = new Comparator<List<Point>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(List<Point> o1, List<Point> o2) {
            int i = o2.get(0).y;
            int j = o1.get(0).y;
            if (i < j) {
                return 1;
            } else if (i > j) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

    };

    Comparator<Point> comparator_columns = new Comparator<Point>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
            int i = o2.x;
            int j = o1.x;
            if (i < j) {
                return 1;
            } else if (i > j) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

    };

    // Sort the rows
    Collections.sort(Llp, comparator_rows);

    // Sort the columns
    for (List<Point> element : Llp) 
        Collections.sort(element, comparator_columns);

    //Print the elements
    int rowIndex = 0, columnIndex=0;

    for (List<Point> row : Llp) 
    {
        for (Point element : row) 
        System.out.print("("+element.x+ "," + element.y +")|");

        System.out.println();
    }
```

The above code gets the first element of each row, and extracts the X coordinate. Then this x coordinate is used to sort all the rows.

### Update

If your data is all mixed up, you can use the following code that uses TreeMaps to put your elements where they are supposed to be. The result is a jagged array.

```
//Create the Data

        List<List<Point>> Llp = new ArrayList<List<Point>>();

        for(int i=0; i< 50; i++)
        {
            List<Point> lp = new ArrayList<Point>();

            for(int j=0; j<50; j++)
            lp.add(new Point((int)(Math.random()*1000), (int)(Math.random()*1000)));

            Llp.add(lp);
        }


        //If all data is mixed up we need to filter into new rows based on X using a TreeMap

        TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer,Point>> data = new TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,Point>>();

        for (List<Point> row : Llp) 
        {
            for (Point element : row) 
            {
                TreeMap<Integer,Point> rowForX;
                if(data.containsKey(element.x))
                    rowForX = data.get(element.x);
                else
                    data.put(element.x, rowForX = new TreeMap<Integer,Point>());    
                    //Create specific row in TreeMap

                rowForX.put(element.y,element);
            }           
        }


        //Convert Sorted TreeMap(s) to Lists

        Llp.clear();
        Iterator<Entry<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Point>>> it = data.entrySet().iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
            Llp.add(new ArrayList<Point>(it.next().getValue().values()));


        //Print the elements
        int rowIndex = 0, columnIndex=0;

        for (List<Point> row : Llp) 
        {
            for (Point element : row) 
            System.out.print("("+element.x+ "," + element.y +")|");

            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: sorry I still have a question, is there any way to make this comparator compare both x and y?

Comment: sure, just add an inner `if` statement at the places that currently say `return 0;`

Comment: A comparator is basically used to compare elements within a list. As you have lists within lists, you need to do one sort of the external list, and another sort for each list within the list. I've updated my code doing exactly that. Question is, do you have your Points already groups into rows of Y's or is all the data mixed up?

Comment: @meewoK all the data is mixed up. The only thing I have is that each point is defined with its x and y coordinates. I'll add a screenshot of my console to my question so that it gets clearer.

Comment: If all your data is mixed up, it means you also need to move elements from one row to another depending on the value of x (row value) ... right? So your 2D array is jagged and not perfectly square...?

Comment: Yes, you can use a map to basically create new groups (rows) of elements. As you want them sorted, I've added an example that uses treemaps. Treemaps automatically sort based on key so when your iterate through them results are sorted.

Comment: @meewoK Thank you :) It has done all the work for me :D Finally.