# How to sort list of list in java

Tags: java, sorting

I have list of list String named as mainPartition: [[23423],[23133],[32323],[23211]]
input file is:

now I want to sort this mainPartition, But it dont work for me

code I used is:

```
Collections.sort(mainPartition, new Comparator<List<String>> () {
    public int compareTo(List<String> a, List<String> b) {
        return a.get(1).compareTo(b.get(1));
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, but same problem persist

Comment: What is the concrete type of `a` and `b`? (List is only an interface).

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1080057).

Comment: There is some information missing as I don't see how that code would have even compiled without the proper method being implemented.

Answer (score 3):

While implementing Comparator, you need to implement **compare(Object o1, Object o2)**. Refer [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Below is the corrected implementation:

```
 Collections.sort(mainPartition, new Comparator<List<String>> () {
        @Override
        public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
            return o1.get(1).compareTo(o2.get(1));
        }
  });
```

Moreover, **if you need natural ordering you should directly use**

```
Collections.sort(collection),
```

provided the class implements Comparable.

Comment: It is a List of List of Strings. Also if the proper method wasn't implemented, the compiler would have thrown an error stating the same.

Comment: Thanks R.J for pointing out List<List<String>>. Update the answer accordingly.